# What is the differential operator in matrix from in the delta function basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

If we take a basis $|n\rangle$ then the matrix elements of differential operator in this basis is given by $D_{mn}=\langle m|\frac{d}{dx}|n\rangle$

Now according to the definition, $\delta(x-x_n)$ is not continuous at $x=x_n$; and therefore it is not differentiable. So if I take the basis $|n\rangle=\delta(x-x_n)$, I cant obtain the $D$ matrix. Nevertheless, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135128/473948) shows the differential of the delta function is in fact zero. In that case $D$ will be a zero matrix!

However I found people occasionally say that $\delta(x-x_n)$ can be taken as a complete orthogonal basis while dealing with differential equations. How is that? Can you discuss with specific example?

Comment: The derivative of the Dirac delta distribution is *not* zero. In the answer you refer to another, closely related, function.

Comment: What is $x_n$ and what makes you think that $\delta(x-x_n)$ is a basis?